# Java how does child class use the variables which is in some function() of parent class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, parent-child

I wrote a piece of code as following:

```
class MyParent {
    String a = "abcdefg";
    String b;
    public void print() {
        b = "ABCDEFG";
        System.out.println(a);  
    }
}
class MyChild extends MyParent {
    String c = super.b;
    public void print2() {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}

public class Parent {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyParent mp = new MyParent();
        mp.print();
        MyChild mc = new MyChild();
        mc.print2();    
    }
}
```

There are two classes and they are parent&child.
There is a `b` declared in the `class MyParent` , and is given a value in the function `print()` .
I wanna print `b` in the child class `MyChild`. But if I run the code, it can print a correctly, but `b` shows `null`.

I'm new to Java. Please help me about it.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to everyone answers my question. I found the solution.

I used the simplest way. I changed it into `**static String b**`.

static makes my arguments can be used all around.

But I don know the exact way of using data declarations. So I will keeping learning.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html , http://www.javaworld.com/article/2987426/core-java/java-101-inheritance-in-java-part-1.html

Comment: You've created two entirely separate objects - `mp.b` will be `"ABCDFEF"`, but `mc.b` is `null` because you're never setting it to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It prints `null` because in `MyParent` class you declared it as an empty `String`. You initialized `b` in `print()` method. So if you want to take value of `b` you can do this:

```
MyChild mc = new MyChild();
mc.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

The instance of mp and mc objects are different. So the value of b is set to "ABCDEFG" in object mp but mc.b is still null.

Try calling `mc.print()` and then `mc.print2()`

However if you want different instances of object's to share the same value of b on updating, then you can make `b` as static.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call

```
print()
```

method of MyParent to initialize **"b"**. You are not initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

when u make extend class evry method and attributes who got protected and less go to the child now if the parent got string b the child also got string b 
if u want the string b of the child will be the same value of string b in parent u make a constructor and make inside the constructor **this.b=super.b** and its mean when u create the  object of the child class its initialize the attribute .
now in this code u should not initialize attribute like that in object oriented.

```
    class MyParent {
            String a = "abcdefg";
            String b="ABCDEFG";

            public MyParent(){}

            public void print() {
                System.out.println(a);  
            }
        }

    class MyChild extends MyParent {
        public MyChild(){
         this.b =super.b;
    }
        public void print2() {  

          System.out.println(b); 
    }
}

    public class Parent {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            MyParent mp = new MyParent();
            mp.print();
            MyChild mc = new MyChild();
            mc.print2();    
        }
    }
```